# Make <embed> take up entire height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using an `<embed>` element so I can render a PDF inline.  It works well in all browsers, but I can't figure out how to have the `<embed>` take up the entire, available height in my Bootstrap column.  [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/GOFAiRVAsgmtaRlJY26L?p=preview) is a Plunker.  You'll need to widen the preview pane to see the columns next to each other.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div id="pdf-container">
          <div id="pdf">
            <embed width="100%" type="application/pdf" src="http://pdf.pdf">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        Other stuff here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the CSS that isn't completely working:

```
#pdf-container {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
}
#pdf-container #pdf {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I'm challenged with is that it seems like you need to set the height directly on the '` element so they even render.  Setting the width on them to 100% is effective, but I can't get the height to take up 100% of the available height.

**UPDATE**: There appear to be a series of Bootstrap classes (.`embed-responsive`) that may be aimed at handling this, but when I apply it, my `<embed>` doesn't appear at all.  Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CUzcY7AlWWQ5T7hljoWW?p=preview) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put mine in responsive iframes. Change the padding-bottom and padding-top: 30px; to suit your needs

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.Flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Flexible-container iframe,
.Flexible-container object,
.Flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
  <object width="100%" data="https://modelica.org/events/modelica2012/authors-guide/example-abstract.pdf?scrollbar=0&amp;toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0" type="application/pdf">
          <embed width="100%" type="application/pdf" src="https://modelica.org/events/modelica2012/authors-guide/example-abstract.pdf?scrollbar=0&amp;toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0">
        </object>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the use of an iframe required for this to work because I simply added your styles and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the code local on on a code pen? Can you post what you tried? This also works http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/yeBqOY

Comment: I tried your styles in my local environment.  I did not include an iframe, though.  I ported your codepen html and css to a Plunker where I could see the results better and it's not working at all.  http://plnkr.co/edit/uw6OZdOx4KyTielKHtWx?p=preview

Comment: I just noticed there is appears to be built-in Bootstrap classes to do what you're doing (`.embed-responsive`).  When I apply this, nothing appears. https://plnkr.co/edit/CUzcY7AlWWQ5T7hljoWW?p=preview